# Return Child Properties In ElasticSearch Query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have had to refactor some of my code in my app to use a Child/Parent relationship in ElasticSearch. I use the Parent as the main search object, and use HasChild to filter on any child properties.

As it stands now, the return object is the complete parent object. But in my code, I also require access to some of the child properties (Namely the child ID). Is this possible to be returned in the result set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need data from the child, then you're actually looking for a query on the child object with a `has_parent` clause to filter by some condition on the parent.

Think of it this way: your results should include one hit per matching child, even if two children share the same parent. So the primary object you're searching is actually the child and not the parent.

You could also consider using a [(<s>`top-children`</s> deprecated since ~1.7)](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/1.7/top-children.html) [`has-child`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.0/query-dsl-has-child-query.html) query which would give you parents and their matching children, however this requires some estimations regarding how many children you expect to see per parent.